# Export SharePoint 2007 site with content to SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2007, upgrade

Current we have SharePoint 2007 (Moss). Now are planning to upgrade (not exactly upgrade, creating new one) to SharePoint 2013 Foundation Server. So I want export couple of sites with content directly to SharePoint 2013 Foundation Server.

What are the options I have? Any good artical or blog explains this?

Answer (score 0):

Their is no direct way to upgrade from 2007 to 2013.There are couple of ways to get this done.

1. OOTB, you have to adopt the database upgrade process, in which you need a SharePoint 2010 farm. You have to upgrade the database to SharePoint 2010 first then to upgrade to 2013.
2. if you have only want to move the content then you can try to move manully from 2007 to 2013.
3. Another way, use the 3rd party tools i.e Sharegate or Metalogix or Ave point. all having the trial to test.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Premier-Field-Engineering/Can-I-upgrade-from-SharePoint-2007-directly-to-SharePoint-2013/ba-p/333272